# Прикрепление файла в форме php

Tags: php

Может кто-нибудь подскажет, как добавить в форму обратной связи, загрузку файла, чтобы этот файл на почту приходил вместе с заявкой?

Код формы

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">                   
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Код обработчика формы

```
<?php
$to = "mail@gmail.com";

$headers= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <admin@admin.com>\r\n";

$name  = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone  = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$message = "Ваше имя: $name <br>Ваш телефон: $phone";

$subject = "";
mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: https://myrusakov.ru/php-mail-attach.html

Comment: https://denis-creative.com/contact-form-with-attached-file/